# Facebook FBOpenGraphAction user message not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm uploading a photo as an open graph object, then tying it into my open graph action once it returns the URL.

Everything is working great so far, but ***I'm not able to get the custom user message "TEST TEST TEST TEST!" to show up.***  I've been hitting this issue from all angles and can't seem to get it nailed down.  Any ideas?

[image]

```
    - (void)postPhotoThenOpenGraphAction {

        FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

        // First request uploads the photo.
        FBRequest *request1 = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:picture.pathSmall]]];

        [connection addRequest:request1 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {
            } else {
                [self showFacebookFailedError];
            }
        }
                batchEntryName:@"photopost"];


        // Second request retrieves photo information for just-created
        // photo so we can grab its source.
        FBRequest *request2 = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"{result=photopost:$.id}"];

        [connection addRequest:request2 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             if (!error && result) {

                 NSString *source = [result objectForKey:@"source"];
                 [self postOpenGraphActionWithPhotoURL:source];

             } else {
                 [self showFacebookFailedError];
             }
         }
         ];

        [connection start];


       }

    - (void)postOpenGraphActionWithPhotoURL:(NSString*)photoURL {

        id<PTOGPicture> photoGraphObject = [self pictureObjectForPicture:self.picture];
        id<PTOGSharePicture> action = (id<PTOGSharePicture>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

        action.photo = photoGraphObject;

        if (self.selectedPlace) {
            action.place = self.selectedPlace;
        }
        if (self.selectedFriends.count > 0) {
            action.tags = self.selectedFriends;
        }

        action.message = @"TEST TEST TEST TEST!";

        if (photoURL) {

            NSMutableDictionary *image = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [image setObject:photoURL forKey:@"url"];

            NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [images addObject:image];

            action.image = images;
        }

        // Create the request and post the action to the.
        [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/myappapp:share"
                                           graphObject:action
                                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                         id result,
                                                         NSError *error) {
           //... code taken out for brevity

        }];
       }
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Custom message is not working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler version that works for what you want:

First you create your action object as you wish:

```
- (void)shareOnFacebook {
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
    action[@"<OPEN_GRAPH_OBJ>"] = obj;
    action[@"image[0][url]"] = url;
    action[@"image[0][user_generated]"] = @"true";
    action[@"message"] = @"some message here";

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/<app_namespace>:<action>" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

However, the requirement for this to work, is that you must have these two permissions set on the action setup page:

[image]

I hope it helps.